# Keeping an aluminium dish in a convection microwave

Tags: aluminum-cookware

Wanted to know if I could use my aluminium tray in my Onida convection microwave.

Comment: On convection mode or microwave mode?

Comment: This is more of an [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) question than a cooking one, but answer posted anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A combo oven acts no differently in each separate mode, than they would as single separate appliances. Metal in a microwave = light show and ruined oven. Metal in convection oven is perfectly ok. Just don’t use any microwave AT ALL when cooking in any metal pan

Comment: It's not as clear cut as that. In mine the manual states you *must* use its round metal dish on combination modes. No arcing takes place. These modes use reduced microwave power but there's no arcing if you leave it in on full power

Answer (score 0):

According to [the manual I found on-line](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/627520/Onida-Power-Convection-20.html?page=6#manual) first item on Page 8, section

> **MATERIALS TO BE AVOIDED IN MICROWAVE OVEN**

[As per manual: All caps, Red.]

> **Aluminium Tray:** May cause arcing. Transfer food in microwave-safe dish.

So not in Combined nor Microwave mode; but Page 7 of the same manual does not warn against  doing the same in convection mode, so that should be safe.